# Unit testing using MockMultipartHttpServletRequest (throws NullPointerException in ItemInputStream.makeAvailable)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, jmock

I've written a transformer class that takes an HttpServletRequest and transforms it into another type that holds a pointer to the InputStream from the servlet request. (The idea is to abstract the incoming transport protocol from the request handling, so I could also write a similar transformer from FTP, for instance.)

Now I'm trying to write a unit test for this, and I'm having problems. I've managed to figure out the correct boilerplate to create a valid Multipart HTTP request (using the Spring classes MockMultipartHttpServletRequest and MockMultipartFile), but now I get a NullPointerException in the `initialize()` method of my `UploadRequest` class. I'm guessing the problem is that somehow the stream inside the MockMultipartHttpServletRequest isn't being initialized correctly, but I can't figure out what I should do differently.

Any suggestions would be gratefully accepted!

This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:976)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:886)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:82)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:66)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readBodyData(MultipartStream.java:592)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.discardBodyData(MultipartStream.java:618)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.skipPreamble(MultipartStream.java:637)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:984)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.getItemIterator(ServletFileUpload.java:148)
    at com.ooyala.UploadRequest.initialize(UploadRequest.java:51)
    at com.ooyala.UploadRequestTest.testCreateFromServletRequest(UploadRequestTest.java:57)
```

Here's an abbreviated version of my transformer class:

```
public class UploadRequest {
  private Map<String, String> params;
  private InputStream strIn;
  private Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(UploadRequest.class.getName());

  public UploadRequest()
  {
    params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  }

  public void initialize(HttpServletRequest sRequest, 
                         ServletFileUpload upload)
    throws IOException, FileUploadException
  {
    Enumeration<String> paramNames = sRequest.getParameterNames();
    while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      String pName = paramNames.nextElement();
      params.put(pName, sRequest.getParameter(pName));
    }
    params.put("request_uri", sRequest.getRequestURI());

    FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(sRequest);
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      FileItemStream item = iter.next();
      try {
        if (!item.isFormField()) {
          // Skip form fields
          params.put("original_file_name", item.getName());
          strIn = item.openStream();
        } 
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.severe("File uploading exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
      }
    }
  }
```

And here's the unit test:

```
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
// etc.... other imports

@RunWith(JMock.class)
public class UploadRequestTest {
  private UploadRequest upRequest;

  @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
      context.setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
      upRequest = new UploadRequest();
    }

  @Test
    public void testCreateFromServletRequest()
      throws IOException, FileUploadException
    {
      String text_contents = "hello world";

      MockMultipartHttpServletRequest sRequest = 
        new MockMultipartHttpServletRequest();
      sRequest.setMethod("POST");
      String boundary = generateBoundary();
      String contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary;
      sRequest.setContentType(contentType);
      sRequest.setRequestURI("/foo");
      sRequest.addParameter("test_param","test_value");
      sRequest.addFile(
        new MockMultipartFile("file1","test_upload.txt","text/plain",
          text_contents.getBytes()));

      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
      assertTrue(upload.isMultipartContent(sRequest));

      upRequest.initialize(sRequest, upload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and I googled but no answer.  I plugged in the source code from the library, You need to send content, whatever. The library might need to check if it is null in the skip method

```
MockMultipartHttpServletRequest request
request.setContent("whatever".getBytes());
```

Posted here for others

Answer (score 1):

1. Add boundary condition
2. Generate contents as follows

   ```
   MockMultipartHttpServletRequest request = 
       this.generateMockMultiPartHttpServletRequest(true);
   MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = null;
   try {
       request.setContentType("multipart/form-data; boundary=-----1234");
       request.setCharacterEncoding("text/plain");
       String endline = "\r\n";
       String bondary = "-----1234";
       String textFile = this.encodeTextFile("-----1234", "\r\n", "file","test.csv",
           "text/UTF-8", FileUtils.readFileToString((new File(csvFilePath)), "UTF-8"));
       StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder(textFile.toString());
       content.append(endline);
       content.append(endline);
       content.append(endline);
       content.append("--");
       content.append(bondary);
       content.append("--");
       content.append(endline);
       request.setContent(content.toString().getBytes());
       request.setMethod("POST");
       mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",
       FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(csvFilePath)));
   } catch (Exception e1) {
       e1.printStackTrace();
   }
    request.addFile(mockMultipartFile);
   ```

Function to encode text

```
    private String encodeTextFile(String bondary, String endline, String name, 
        String filename, String contentType, String content) {

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
        sb.append(endline);
        sb.append("--");
        sb.append(bondary);
        sb.append(endline);
        sb.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
        sb.append(name);
        sb.append("\"; filename=\"");
        sb.append(filename);
        sb.append("\"");
        sb.append(endline);
        sb.append("Content-Type: ");
        sb.append(contentType);
        sb.append(endline);
        sb.append(endline);
        sb.append(content);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem, after searching lot I got this post in which I answered with code that solved my problem.

The Shriprasad's solution works well for text file. But I had some problems with binary files.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30541653/2762092