# Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly while running junit test case for servlet

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, junit

I am writing multipart file upload test case in servlet but it is throwing exception as mention:
Code:

```
public class MessageUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List uploadedItems = null;
try {
uploadedItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
upload.setSizeMax(10485760);
} catch (FileUploadException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}}}
```

I am taking reference to write unit test from mention location
[How to use spring's MockMultipartHttpServletRequest? Getting "no multipartboundary was found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642012/how-to-use-springs-mockmultiparthttpservletrequest-getting-no-multipartbounda/47987991#47987991)

Exception:

> 2018-01-04 18:38:15 ERROR MessageUploadServlet:157 - Processing of
>   multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException:
>   Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended
>   unexpectedly  at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:371)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
>     at
>   tm.servlet.MessageUploadServlet.doPost(MessageUploadServlet.java:74)
>     at
>   tm.servlet.MessageUploadServletTest.testServlet(MessageUploadServletTest.java:25)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException:
>   Stream ended unexpectedly     at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:982)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:886)
>     at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:96)  at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:66)  at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:366)
>     ... 26 more

Comment: "Stream ended unexpectedly" means that the client has sent an incomplete request. You should provide more information about your code and the client.